# How to add values from a cell list to existing values in cells

Tags: excel, vba, list, cell

In Microsoft Excel, I have two columns in a sheet. The first column has values like `B2`,`A13`,`BB125` and the next column has some number values like `12`,`569`,`78`.

I want to find the cell from the first column in another sheet and to that cell add the value from the second column.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value from the cell in column A and pass it to `Range()` to address the cell in your other sheet.

For example:

```
' Use A1 as an example...
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1")

' Use A1's value to address a cell on Sheet2 and assign the value from B1...
Sheet2.Range(r.Value).Value = r.Offset(, 1).Value
```